# How to explain a frequency pic at 1.5 kHz?

Tags: signal-identification, gnuradio, vlf

I have a pic in the VLF band at 1.5 kHz. **What would be the origin of this peak?**

The graph was obtained by running `display_qt` in Linux from a laptop.

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  We recommend all new users take [the tour](http://ham.stackexchange.com/tour) to get the most from the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`display_qt` is a GNU Radio example program. It does not display any actually existing electromagnetic signal but internally generates a 1500 Hz sinusoid.

[The code](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/repository/revisions/9db614d652ca5065599d4282bd43a3b3fd0e9d12/entry/gr-qtgui/examples/c++/display_qt.cc) creates a sine source and a noise source,

```
// Source will be sine wave in noise
src0 = analog::sig_source_f::make(rate, analog::GR_SIN_WAVE, 1500, 1);
src1 = analog::noise_source_f::make(analog::GR_GAUSSIAN, 0.1);
```

then sums them and sends that to the displays.